# Select2 allows to select "wrong item" when populating items with ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, jquery-select2

Please check the image attached

I'm working with select2 4.0 and am populating items into the select by using ajax calls. All is working fine. I can do incremental search and this speeds a lot.

**The problem is that select2 allows user to select this "temporary item" generated dynamically from what user writes in the box...**

Does anyone know how should I disable selection of this item? Or at least validate in the button click that this item should not be selected...

[image]

Comment: What happens if a user actually selects this option? You could maybe just disable the first option on change?

Comment: @Glubus user can select the option and submit the form. This item has text and value so there's no validation error; but the logic is wrong because this item usually does not exist in db

Comment: What about my second suggestion, disabling the row through javascript. I understand that you'd like to not meddle with the library, but I'm fairly sure you're able to access the selectwindow on change. Just disable the first option: $.("#select2thing").firstChild().prop("disabled",true);

Comment: Also, considering that you're worried about your server giving an error, you always need to do serverside validation (i.e. does the value exist in the database). The user can just modify the html on his side, causing errors because of that.

Comment: Hi @Glubus . Check what I've posted. My mistake :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reviewed the entire code and noticed I had these 2 options enabled in the select2 init. I removed them and now all is working fine.

```
tags: true,
tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
```

I must have left them copied from some example copied/pasted

Hope it can be useful for someone with same problem in future

Comment: Glad that you worked it out, make sure to close your question by accepting your own answer as the solution to your problem.